# How to get entities with limit and offset and get total count of them

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select entities with limit and offset and get total count of them. Query example:

```
select *, count(`commissions`.`id`) as total_count
from `commissions`
where `commissions`.`deleted_at` is null
limit 5 offset 0
```

For example I have 7 commissions and I need to get total_count = 7 and first 5 commissions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select c.*, count(*) over () as total_count
from commissions c
where c.deleted_at is null
limit 5 offset 0;
```

This puts the value in each row.  If you want the value separately, you can use [`CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#id959825).

Comment: I cannot understand hot to `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` work

Comment: I trying something like 
`select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
from commissions c
where c.deleted_at is null
limit 2 offset 0;` but it returned just my entities